# Limiting Memory Leak on object not under your control

Tags: c#, object, memory-leaks

I have a method that was created by someone else and do not have access to the source. This Method creates a PDF document on the file system, but I'm having issues with memory when I start passing it 200+ images.
From what I can tell it loads the object into memory in order to render the PDF, and then outputs to the file system. When I use a for or foreach loop to interate through my files and output them I can see in task manager the memory is building slowly, it does dip from time to time, but in general it's always on the way up.

Here's my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Documents.Count; i++)
{    
    IDocument document = Documents[i];
    try
    {        
        string exportFileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}", batchName, document.Field("NHS File\\SectionName").Text, document.Field("NHS File\\Classification Result").Text, dateTime);
        string imageFileName = exportFileName;


            int tries = 0;
            while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(processingLocation, imageFileName + ".pdf")))
            {
                imageFileName = string.Format("{0}_{1}", exportFileName, tries++);
            } 
            document.SaveAs((Path.Combine(processingLocation, imageFileName)), ExportOptions.GetImageOptions()); 

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Processing.ReportError(ex.ToString());
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(document);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(document);
        document = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
}
```

The issue is with the 'document.SaveAs();'
I've tried calling the garbage collectors and release COM objects, adding and removing memory pressure, but nothing seems to work I continually get "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Not enough memory!" when it gets to 200 files.

There seems to be no close(), Dispose(), or Finalise() options with this.

Is there a way of calling this document.SaveAs() so that the memory used by the object is controlled and released by me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do this code in a separate process that your current code executes with `Process.Start`. Exiting a process is a pretty much (the only) guaranteed way to clean up all of the resources owned by the process if you don't have control over the 3rd party code.

Comment: Agree with @vcsjones and that would actually be my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'm not so familiar with Process.Start am currently looking at some examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the 3rd party code, you have little options to clean up the memory. The nature of the code seems to imply that it is heavy in COM Interop or platform invoke, which are a sure-fire way to leak memory if done incorrectly. `GC.Collect` doesn't collect natively allocated memory since it is outside of the garbage collector's knowledge.

I would recommend putting your logic in a separate process, and when the processing is complete, letting the process exit. Exiting a process is a very reliable way to clean up resources and memory.

Move your code into a console app, and use [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) to start your new command line utility from your current code. Use `WaitForExit` if you want to do is synchronously, and you can pass in arguments to the process such as the path of files or directories to process.